# Ho to format an each loop in a bootstrap table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I would like to format and each loop in a bootstrap table
So this is my code of my bookshelper.js file:

```
  Template.books.helpers({
  'book': function(){ 
        return Books.find();
        }     
  });
```

In my books.html file I've added a bootstrap table:

```
   <table class="table table-striped">
   <tr>
     <th>Author</th>
     <th>Title</th>
   </tr>
   {{#each book}}
     <tbody>{{author}} </tbody> 
     <tbody>{{title}}  </tbody>   
   {{/each}}   
   </table>
```

this is the result:
  http://gyazo.com/52870c76370bed527757a3c7fd5972d5
  Both author and title results are under one column(author) how can I divide them in the 2 respective columns ? My Books mongo collection is very simple. it has just  an **author** and a **title** attributes. Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: Do you know how to create a simple table ? body > tr > td ?

Answer (score 0):

[For reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15440836/1439597), tables are designed this way:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Author</td>
      <td>Some Title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Other Author</td>
      <td>Some Other Title</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- etc -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

From this example, try to use your `each` statement around the parts that clearly need to be repeated. There should be only one `table`, one `thead`, and one `tbody` (along with their `/table`, `/thead` and `/tbody` of course) in the HTML code resulting from your template processing.